# Tiling image to be used with Google Maps?

Tags: raster, tiles, tools

I have a 2880 x 2880 image that I would like to tile so that it replace the entire usual world map.

So far I got this working

```
gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-6 5KNewMap.png abc3/
```

but for the zoom level 0 the tile is not centred and there is a kind of white border around.

What is the best and easiest way to tile my picture so that It replace the entiere world map?

Also I'm getting really confused with the difference between "raster" and "Mercator" ? If I use "Mercator" it asks me for some points but I don't which one to set so that it covers all the world.

Comment: Is this image georeferenced? What format is it in?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is a plain .PNG file

Comment: 256x256 tiles is required.

Comment: A single tile is indeed 256x256